# what happens when increment counter and test counter are interchanged in for-loop syntax?

Tags: c, for-loop

please explain why
**Case 1:**

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i++;i<100)
        printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

results in infinite loop, whereas
**Case 2:**

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i++;i<100)
        printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't run the loop even once?
Please clarify how to interpret this kind of syntax?

Comment: Bad formatting, please fix. You don't even indent the `printf()`. Can't you find anything about C `for`-loops?

Comment: Arrrghhh!  Another 'what happens if I write stupid code' question.

Comment: 'how to interpret this kind of syntax?' - an extremely bad example to any future SO visitor, (and also crap).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'I drove my car into a tree, why am I in hospital?'

Comment: @Martin James why? These types of questions are frequently asked in aptitude programming tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The syntax of a for loop in `C programming language` is:**

```
for ( init; condition; increment )
{
   statement(s);
}
```

- Here is the flow of control in a for loop:

  1. The init step is executed first, and only once. This step allows you to declare and initialize any loop control variables. You are not required to put a statement here, as long as a semicolon appears.
  2. Next, the condition is evaluated. If it is true, the body of the loop is executed. If it is false, the body of the loop does not execute and flow of control jumps to the next statement just after the for loop.
  3. After the body of the for loop executes, the flow of control jumps back up to the increment statement. This statement allows you to update any loop control variables. This statement can be left blank, as long as a semicolon appears after the condition.
  4. The condition is now evaluated again. If it is true, the loop executes and the process repeats itself (body of loop, then increment step, and then again condition). After the condition becomes false, the for loop terminates.

### In First Case:

- `init`  set `i = 1`
- `conditon` - here `i = 1` which is `true` in c.  (Post increment increases the value after execution of statment)
- `body`  - executes `printf("%d",i);`
- `increment`  - `i<100` which is not affecting the value of `i`.

Now In C for all values from 1 to infinity, its value is true, hence executing infinetly

### In Second Case

- `init`  set `i = 0`
- `conditon` - here `i = 0` (again Post Increment) which is `false` in c, therefore the `loop` gets exit.

Hence it is not executing even once.

### Flow diagram of For Loop :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The proper syntax is

```
for (i=1; i<100; i++) {
    something
}
```

**What's actually happening?**
The for loop takes three arguments,
 1. The initial condition, or initialization that happens at the beginning, before the loop is executed. In this case it's `i=1` that is set `i` as `1`
 2. The final condition that is checked at the *beginning* of *every* loop. If this condition is not met, the loop is broken. In this case it's `i<100`. So, if at the start of next loop, when `i >= 100` the loop is broken.
 3. The step or periodic operation at the end of loop. In this case it's `i++`. At the end of every loop i is incremented by 1.

**What's happening with your code**

```
for (i=1; i++; i<100)
```

The first part is good.
The second is executed at the beginning of each loop. `i++` returns the value of `i` then increments it. (In contrast to `++i`, which does the opposite.) Since in your first example i=1, it starts at one, and the second argument always returns a value `>= 1` which is interpreted as `true`. But in your second example, i starts at 0. So during first iteration the second argument returns 0, which is interpreted as false, and the loop never starts.
The third one is executed at the end, and never affects the loop in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for( expression1; expression2; expression3)
{
   Single statement
   or
   Block of statements;
}

In the above syntax:

expression1 - Initialisese variables.
expression2 - Condtional expression, as long as this condition is true, loop will keep executing.
expression3 - expression3 is the modifier which may be simple increment of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i++;i<100)
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

as `for` loop is having syntax

```
for(initialize variable; condition check; increment/decrement)
```

you have initialize variable as `i = 0`
in condition checking part you have written `i++` i.e post increment so `i` remain `0` which means `FALSE` and hence it will exit for loop.