# Quick_Sort in Single Linked List

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to apply quick sort on a single linked list.I have created the partition function which works by considering the first element as pivot:

```
list->19->8-17->15->25->41
After calling partition(&list) we get :
list->16->17->8->19->25->41
```

This is what I am trying to do :

1.)I call Quicksort() on list->19->8-17->15->25->41

2.)In QuickSort , We call the partition on list and so I get list->16->17->8->19->25->41 and here 'q' points to the pivot element.

3.)Now using q we split the list in 2 parts : list1->16->17->8->Null and list2->25->41 and then call quicksort on list1 and list 2

4.)Then I join both the lists with 'q'.

But my program crashes in windows probably due to segmentation fault.Can someone please help me out here .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
};

typedef struct node Node;

void display(Node *p){
    while(p!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

Node * create(int d){
    Node *p=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->data=d;
    p->next=NULL;
    return p ;
}

Node * partition(Node **head){
    Node *list=*head;
    Node *pv=*head;
    int pivot=list->data;
    Node *p=list->next;
    Node *temp,*q=list;

    while(1){
        if(!p)
            break;

        if(p->data<pivot){
            temp=p;
            q->next=temp->next;
            p=p->next;
            temp->next=list;
            list=temp;
        }
        else{
            q=p;
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
    *head=list;
    return pv ;
}

Node * quicksort(Node * list){



    if(list==NULL || (list)->next==NULL)
        return list;
    Node * q,*list1,*list2,* temp;
    q=partition(&list);

    list1=list;

    list2=q->next;
    temp=list1;

    while(1){
        if(temp->next==q)
        {
            temp->next=NULL;
            break;

        }
        temp=temp->next;

    }

    list1=quicksort(list1);
    list2=quicksort(list2);
    temp=list1;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=q;
    q->next=list2;
    return list1;
}





int main(){

    Node *list1=create(19),*list2;
    Node *a=create(8);
    Node *b=create(17);
    Node *c=create(16);
    Node *d=create(25);
    Node *e=create(41);
    list1->next=a;a->next=b;b->next=c;c->next=d;d->next=e;

    list1=quicksort(list1);
    display(list1);


}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You mean SO isn't a distributed debugging service?

Comment: @JohnColeman that was last week.  This week, it's answering questions about stupid code that nobody would write, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759349/what-happens-when-increment-counter-and-test-counter-are-interchanged-in-for-loo

Comment: Next week is pencilled in for repeatedly explaining compound boolean expressions in do..while loop conditions.

Comment: @rcgldr That's what I am doing , I am finding out the last element of the first list and setting it to NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in the while(1) loop:

```
       if(temp->next==q)
```

temp can be equal to q (when pivot is smaller than rest of list), so temp->next will never be equal to q, and the segmentation fault occurs when temp->next == NULL, and then does temp = temp->next twice.

A bottom up merge sort would be better, but I'm assuming this is just a learning exercise.

update - a fast bottom up linked list merge sort that uses an array of pointers to nodes, where array[i] points to a list of size 2 to the power i nodes (or it's NULL). Nodes are merged into the array one at a time, then when all nodes are merged into the array, the array is merged to produce a single sorted list.

```
#define NUMLISTS 32                     /* number of lists */

typedef struct NODE_{
struct NODE_ * next;
int data;
}NODE;

NODE * MergeLists(NODE *, NODE *);

NODE * SortList(NODE *pList)
{
NODE * aList[NUMLISTS];                 /* array of lists */
NODE * pNode;
NODE * pNext;
int i;
    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for empty list */
        return NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)       /* zero array */
        aList[i] = NULL;
    pNode = pList;                      /* merge nodes into aList[] */
    while(pNode != NULL){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i] != NULL); i++){
            pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
            aList[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == NUMLISTS)
            i--;
        aList[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    pNode = NULL;                       /* merge array into one list */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)
        pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}

NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                      /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;                   /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    while(1){
        if(pSrc1 == NULL){
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            break;
        }
        if(pSrc2 == NULL){
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            break;
        }
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            continue;
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            continue;
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}
```

Comment: Yes,this was the problem.Thanks a lot.I changed my code and now it works fine.